# How to get different instances of an object created using a Random Value node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using 3.1.

(This question has been edited. The previous sample file incompletely matched the description and didn't allow full answers. I've just aligned the description of the problem and the sample file.)

I'm working on the base of a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQaJrciGgYQ) to create procedural grass: A leaf is created, then instanced on points of a small surface to create a tuft. Several tufts are then distributed to cover a larger area. I've reduced the leaf to a tube for simplification.

A tuft composed of randomly oriented and scaled tubes:

[image]

The nodes to build this geometry:

[image]

The tuft is built from leaf instances which are rotated and scaled randomly. So far, so good. The problem arises when tuft instances are used to make a grass area:

[image]

Tufts are built from leaves similar in number, orientation and size. Not very realistic. Here my tree for the tuft:

[image]

**What would be the correct way to introduce variations in tufts?**

From quellenform's answer I learned instances are all based on a single mesh, but can be realized into separate entities and vertices positions changed using `Set Position` nodes. Still I can't see how I could do this adjustment to perform rotation and scaling of individual leaves. The reason is leaves to be modified are now instances of instances made real. This nesting prevents me to access them from the top-level node group.

The corresponding file:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your .blend using [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)? (The sky texture and any other textures etc. are not necessary. Try to keep the file small.)

Comment: @Mentalist: I added a sample file.

Answer (score 2):

With the node `Instance on Points` you always create copies (!) of a single object.

You can find this problem in several posts here on BSE.

During or after an instantiation you always only have access to the transformation of the objects, but the mesh remains the same for all instances.

**Instance == Duplicate!**

But you can use the node `Realize Instances` afterwards, and move the single vertices with `Set Position` to a new position:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

You can achieve the desired end result, but you would have to structure it differently.

If you create a node group for the grass bale and instantiate it, all instances (copies) are identical.

After an instantiation you only have the possibility to change the rotation, position or scaling of individual instances, or, if you convert the instances with `Realize Instances` into a mesh, to move the individual vertices.

However, to create individual grass balls with different distribution of points and to keep the parts parameterizable, you would first have to create the individual surfaces of the grass balls, and then collectively distribute the individual points for the instantiation of the grass blades.

[image]
[image]

The node group for this could look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a helpful explanation. "Instance" use by Blender is misleading, in type theory an instance can have its own state, only the behavior is fixed. To clarify furthermore `Realize Instances` seem to be the new wording for converting clones (aka linked meshes) into independent meshes, is it correct?

Comment: @mins Well, this is not type theory... and this definition of instancing is not limited to Blender. Quote from Wikipedia: "_geometry instancing is the practice of rendering multiple copies of the same mesh_". The **same mesh** is crucial here. You can scale, rotate, move instances as well and create random versions of them in Geometry Nodes, just like e.g. doing those transformations in _Object Mode_. But you cannot change the underlying mesh, and if you do it in _Edit Mode_, the instances change as well. So if you want to change them invidually, you have to unlink them somehow.

Comment: @mins That's right: `Realize Instances` means that each individual instance is converted into a mesh and these are packaged together in one *Geometry*. This geometry can then be further processed as usual. "Independent" therefore only in the sense of *Mesh Islands*.

Comment: Now I understand (a bit) better instances, your comment mentioning Mesh Islands makes me think my original problem (rotating and scaling leaves) cannot be solved after the leaf instances are realized, because they are not anymore a single object. E.g. if I use a `Transform` node, I can rotate/scale the whole mesh created, that is all leaves at once, but not the individual islands. Or do I miss something...?

Comment: @mins ...not exactly: Instances you convert to a mesh with `Realize Instances` behave exactly the same as when you join several meshes to one object with *Join* (CTRL+J). The mesh topology is independent and the vertices are connected with faces. For example, if you instantiate and realize two cubes, you have two *Mesh Islands*, but both cubes are combined into one object. You can modify all parts (vertices, edges, faces, etc.) beyond the transformation at any time (e.g. with `Set Position`).

Comment: @mins `Transform` always modifies the entire object (all contained points are modified equally). However, `Set Position` works per *Vertex/Edge/Face* after you have applied `Realize Instances`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. If `Transform` doesn't work on islands, then I cannot scale/rotate islands. That was my problem in the question (not in the sample file).

Comment: @mins You can also rotate/scale single vertices (or parts of your mesh) with the node `Set Position`. But you would have to calculate the vectors (for example with `Vector Rotate` or other vector nodes).

Comment: Again thanks. I tried your suggestion but no joy. Rather than continuing asking details in comments, I've reworked the text of my question and also added a new file which is completely in line with the description.